# Describe Mathematically and graphically the region represented by $\ -\pi \lt arg (z) \lt \pi $

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been told to determine Mathematically and graphically the region represented by $\ -\pi \lt  arg  (z) \lt \pi $.But I have failed to determine it.But I have determined one for $\ 1 \lt |z+i| \le 2 $ I have determined it like below:

$\ 1 \lt |z+i| \le 2 $

=> $\ 1 \lt |(x+iy)+i| \le 2 $

=> $\ 1 \lt |(x+i(y+1)| \le 2 $

=> $\ 1 \lt \sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2} \le 2 $

=> $\ 1^2 \lt  {(x+0)^2+(y+1)^2} \le 2^2 $

So,form above derivation,It is clear that the,if we plot it on graph it will represent a circle which center will be $\ (0,-1)$ and the redius  will vary from $\ 1 \lt r \le 2 $.

But I am unable to determine so for $\ -\pi \lt  arg  (z) \lt \pi $.

Comment: looks like you have the right half plane with $Re(z)>0$

Comment: @WW1 I disagree, this is rather the set $\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$.
Do you know how the argument (and the absolute value) of a complex number  can be seen in the complex plane?

Comment: @lattice  sorry - somehow I was thinking of $-\frac\pi 2 < arg(z) <  \frac\pi 2$

Comment: @WW1 No problem, at a first glance I had the same idea^^

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the argument of a complex number is the angle that $z\in\mathbb{C}$ forms in standard position. Considering the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:-\pi< \arg (z)<\pi\}$, note the radius is not specified. Then we're trying to find all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with argument in $[-\pi,\pi]$. Notice that every point in the complex plane satisfies this condition except for points that lay on the strictly negative real axis. So a simple way to describe this set is all of $\mathbb{C}$ except for the negative real numbers.

Finally, note that zero is an element of the set in question, since the argument of zero is either taken as $0$ or as undefined, depending on the context.